# x >= x pattern in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, d3.js, coding-style, nan

When reading source of D3.js I saw `x >= x` pattern. If it is for detecting NaNs among numbers, why not just `isNaN(x)` or `x == x`?

[Source, where I encountered it](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/d3.js#L52-L67):

```
d3.min = function(array, f) {
  var i = -1, n = array.length, a, b;
  if (arguments.length === 1) {
    while (++i < n) if ((b = array[i]) != null && b >= b) {
      a = b;
      break;
    }
    while (++i < n) if ((b = array[i]) != null && a > b) a = b;
  } else {
    while (++i < n) if ((b = f.call(array, array[i], i)) != null && b >= b) {
      a = b;
      break;
    }
    while (++i < n) if ((b = f.call(array, array[i], i)) != null && a > b) a = b;
  }
  return a;
};
```

Comment: Have a look at the commits that introduced the logic: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/commit/d8c8b5ddd6d433b7c80bc5e3e469fdf277c1aa16, https://github.com/mbostock/d3/commit/aad1b18865f8c73c4267c7505435070f42fa6c40

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks! I was actually looking for some annotated source code, but it seems there is none: [annotated copy of d3.js source code like the one for jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624927/annotated-copy-of-d3-js-source-code-like-the-one-for-jquery)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

From my investigations, `d3.min` is supposed to work on any kind of orderable values, not only numbers. `isNaN` would only work numbers.

d3 was actually using `==` at some point. [This commit](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/commit/2e560f6d6e020b471deb63116345221e7564eb22) introduced the `x == x` test:

> Unlike `Math.min` and `Math.max`, it doesn't make sense to return negative or positive infinity for `d3.min` and `d3.max`; the D3 functions return the minimum value according to an arbitrary ordering, not by numeric value. Instead, the minimum or maximum of an empty array, or an array that contains only degenerate values, should always be undefined.

[This commit](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/commit/aad1b18865f8c73c4267c7505435070f42fa6c40) changed `x == x` to `x <= x` (which was later again changed to `x >= x`):

> In addition to `NaN`, which is not equal to itself, you can have objects that are not orderable due to defined valueOf functions which return NaN. For example:
>
> ```
> var o = new Number(NaN);
> ```
>
> Here, `o == o` is true, but `o <= o` is false. Therefore it was possible for d3.min, d3.max and d3.extent to observe these non-orderable values rather than ignore them as intended. The fix is to check `!(o <= o)` rather than `o == o`.

Comment: +1 coincidentally, `!(o <= o)` is how my face looks when I'm trying to make sense of Javascript's `==` equality rules.

Answer (score 9):

OK, I see that `x >= x` gives `false` for both `NaN` and `undefined`. (Unlike `isNaN(x)` or `x == x`.)

EDIT: While it is one of the use cases of `x >= x`, in this case (thx @Felix Kling for pointing this out) `undefined` is already being checked.

Comment: However, the `undefined` case is already covered with `!= null` anyway.